# How can I get an interactive login with Windows 10 IoT Core running on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: powershell, raspberry-pi, iot, windows-10, raspberry-pi2

I just installed Windows 10 onto a Raspberry Pi. It started up fine and I can connect (using PowerShell) from my laptop.

I can connect a keyboard and mouse to the Pi but I can't get a login window.  All that I can do is change the timezone and reboot.  Is there a way to login directly to the device?

I don't need fancy graphical windows. A command line session (*à la* Linux or PowerShell) would be fine.

If it isn't possible with the core install, does anyone know if Microsoft, or a third party provider, plans to add this feature?

Comment: When you say you can connect via PowerShell, isn't this an interactive session?

Comment: Also, I don't have access to Win10 IoT, but have you tried the usual ways? i.e. Ctrl+Alt+Delete -> Task Manager, or Ctrl+Shift+Escape?

Comment: I agree that powershell is an interactive session, but I want to login directly to the PI bia connected keyboard, mouse and monitor.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a command line presented on the local display. The only way to run commands on Win10 IoT is to use PowerShell as described by Keith in this thread or you can use SSH or Telnet. You can interact with applications run on the device via the local display, keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell remoting from another Windows box to do stuff on Windows 10 IoT Core.  I've tested [this procedure](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm) on Windows 10 PowerShell, works fine.  Be sure to follow the step to `Remove-Module PSReadline`. I was trying to use setcomputername to rename my Raspberry Pi 2 and the command would fail with a command not found error.

Once I removed the PSReadline module, the command started working.  Hopefully Jason gets this fixed as PSReadline is just too valuable to remove for long.